# JAX-WS SoapHandler not invoked when using CXF runtime

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws

I implemented a client library which uses jax-ws to talk to a back-end. I don't control the jax-ws runtime: my customer can choose which one they would like to use. My implementation includes a SoapHandler to handle authentication by inserting credentials in the SOAP header prior to sending the message. I set this handler programmatically using javax.xml.ws.Binding.setHandlerChain().

```
Binding binding = ((BindingProvider)jobMgmtSvc).getBinding();
List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
handlerList.add(new EctsSoapHandler(new MyTokenProvider(authUrl, user, pwd)));
binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
```

Everything works fine when I use the jax-ws runtime of Oracle JRE 1.8. But when I use the CXF runtime (version 3.2.8) my handler is not invoked. Any ideas why ?

Edited: after more troubleshooting, it seems like my problem is that the CXF runtime tries to get a security token on its own via STSClient:

```
    2020-04-27 09:44:59,099  WARN [main] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://tempuri.org/}JobManagement#{http://adlibsoftware.com/}GetJobsStatus has thrown exception, unwinding now
    org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.TrustException: The STSClient is not configured with either a location or wsdlLocation property
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.createClient(AbstractSTSClient.java:680)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.issue(AbstractSTSClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSTokenRetriever.getTokenFromSTS(STSTokenRetriever.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSTokenRetriever.getToken(STSTokenRetriever.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider$IssuedTokenOutInterceptor.handleMessage(IssuedTokenInterceptorProvider.java:144)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:440)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
```

I already implemented a SOAPHandler to retrieve the token, so how can I disable STS and get CXF to use my SOAPHandler implementation? Again, I would like my code to work with any jax-ws runtime, so I don't want to have any CXF dependencies in my code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm just praying that none of my customers will use the CXF runtime.

Comment: Sorry to hear. It is working for me - my fault was to set the handler at the endpoint instead of the binding. Using  
```java

EndpointImpl endpoint;
val handlerChain = endpoint.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
handlerChain.add(new SoapRequestInterceptor());
endpoint.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```
worked for me.